# Show a div on click and hide the other div and oposite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to: When I click a button to have a div1 show and the div2 hide, and when I click it again to do the opposite, div 2 hide and div1 show. I managed to achieve only the first part.

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#insert").on('click', function() {
      $(".subtable").hide();
      $(".insert-field").show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert Subscriber(s)">
    <table class="subtable">...</table>
    <div class="insert-field">...</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toggle()` to change the display of an element. If it is hidden it will be shown. And if shown, will be hidden. That's the easiest way to just flip things back and forth.

The other way would be to either check whether the element is hidden, or keep track of the state in a separate variable to which you can refer to know whether to hide or show.

Comment: Aha, So I change the .hide and .show to toggle for both. Yep Working, will mark as accepted as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.toggle()`. Depending on your implementation, you can set the argument of `.toggle()` as true or false, based on the `.visible` property of another element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $("p").toggle();
});
```

Here is a quick tutorial to help you.

[W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var flag = true;
  $("#button").on('click',function(){
      if(flag == true){
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide();
        flag =false;
       }else{
          $("#div1").hide();
          $("#div2").show();
          flag =true;
         }
   });
```